# How to get class to extend parent in Silex

Tags: php, silex

Is it possible to do this without creating a `ControllerResolver` class? I want `RootController` and `AuthController` to extend `Controller`. I already have the code `... extends Controller` in each of them but Silex doesn't pick it up.

I've also tried but didn't work:

```
$app['controller.root'] = $app->share($app->extend('controller.base', function() use ($app) {
........
```

.

```
// Register Controllers
$app['controller.base'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
   return new Controller(
       $app['twig'],
       $app['session'],
       $app['form.factory'],
       $app['url_generator']);
});

$app['controller.root'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
    return new RootController(
        $app['service.user']);
}));

$app['controller.auth'] = $app->share(function() use ($app) {
   return new AuthController(
        $app['service.google'],
        $app['service.user'],
        $app['service.meetup']);
});
```

I could try `parant::__construct($dependencies......)` in each sub Controller but I think that will start to look messy.

Comment: What do you mean by ```I already have the code ... extends Controller in each of them but Silex doesn't pick it up. ```? If your class *extends* another one, Silex has nothing to do with it, it's plain and simple OOP. And yes, you have to call ```parent::__construct``` in your sub-controllers if the subclass has a special constructor in order for the parent to be initialized. So the way to go is probably what @Fractaliste suggests, instead of using constructor injection use setter and make your controllers ready by extending them (use the ```extend``` method).

Answer (score 0):

You can't extend using constructor, but if you have a setter available you can try:

```
$app['controller.base'] = $app->share($app->extend('controller.base', function($controller) use ($app) {
    $controller->setUser($app['service.user']);
    return $controller;
});
```

Be carefull, your exemple has a logic problem, if you extend a service it should have the same name `'controller.base'`, not a new one like `'controller.root'`.

Comment: I think it would be better to add the link to Pimple documentation. Pimple is  a DI manager which is used by Silex. `Silex\Application` extends `Pimple. So, if you use Silex v1 - read [Pimple v1 documentation](https://github.com/silexphp/Pimple/tree/1.1). Or if you use Silex v2 - [Pimple v3 documentation](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/)